# VBA displaying wrong type of area chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have an area chart which I generated with the following code

```
Sub Macro_1()

Worksheets("My_Sheet").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlArea).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C13:BT22")
        
End Sub
```

And when I use this code it creates the first style of area chart showed on this picture and the one I am trying to generate is the third style (The one at the bottom) and I'm not sure of how to specify this through VBA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `xlArea` with `xlAreaStacked100`. But you can select the chart type creating a `ChartObject`:

```
Dim ch_shape As Shape, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("My_Sheet")
Set ch_shape = ws.Shapes.AddChart2

With ch_shape.Chart
    With .ChartArea
        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(244, 244, 244)
        .height = 300
        .width = 450
        .left = 0
        .top = 350
    End With
    
    .ChartType = xlAreaStacked100 'After adding, intellisense will offer a list of all chart types
    .SetSourceData ws.Range("C13:BT22")
    .HasTitle = False
    .HasLegend = False
    .ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel, , , , , True, , True, , vbLf
    
    With .FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
        .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
        .NumberFormat = "##.00"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @Sam Didn't the above code answer your question?